# What is this C behavior called

Tags: c

I'm learning C as Javascript developer and a common mistake that I make is when I'm supposed to define multiple variables in C like this

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 0;
```

I accidentally do it the Javascript way

```
a,b,c = 0;
```

I'm wondering what the above is called and when I should define variables like this.

Comment: `a,b,c = 0;` does not define variables.   `int a, b, c;` is a 3x variable definition.  `a,b,c = 0;`  assigns `c` with the value of 0.

Comment: `a = b = c = 0;` is a right to left evaluation, to assign 4 variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I'm wondering what the above is called....*

Two things about this statement

```
a,b,c = 0;
```

**First**, this is same as

```
a;
b;
c = 0;
```

The expression `a;` and `b;` result is unused.

The compiler must be throwing warning messages on this statement. When I compiled with `clang` compiler, I am getting following warnings:

```
p.c:6:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        a, b, c = 9;

        ^
p.c:6:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        a, b, c = 9;
           ^
```

and **Second**, the `,` in the statement is `,` (comma) operator.

Precisely stated, the meaning of the comma operator in the general expression

```
e1 , e2
```

is evaluate the subexpression `e1` and discards the result , then evaluate `e2`; the value of the expression is the value of `e2`.

So, the value of expression `a,b,c = 0` is value of `c = 0`. The variable `a` and `b` will remain *uninitialised*.

May you can try this and check the variable values after this statement:

```
a = 99, b = 5, c = 0;
```

Since you are learning C, let me tell you one more thing - The `,` (comma) act as separator in function calls and definitions, variable declarations, enum declarations, and similar constructs. To begin with, check **[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator#Examples)**.

> *and when I should define variables like this.*

The statement `a,b,c = 0;` is not definition of variable `a`, `b` and `c`. You have defined the variable `a`, `b` and `c` here

```
int a, b, c;
```

Note that in this statement, the `,` is act as separator.

Its use is completely depends on you as long as you know very well about it. One of the very common use of `,` (comma) operator is in `for` loop, where it can be used to initialise multiple variables and/or increment/decrement loop counter variable and other variables etc., for example :

```
for (i = 0, j = some_num; i < some_num; ++i, --j) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide it up by the operators:

```
int a, b;
a = b = 10;
^   ^^^^^^
|   Right operand
Left operand
```

Here, first it calculates `b = 10` to assign to `a`. `b = 10` "returns" the new value of `b` which is 10, and that is assigned to `a`. It works similarly with more variables:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 10;
        ^^^^^^-Done first
    ^^^^^-Done second
^^^^^-Done last
```

`a, b, c = 10` does not work the same way. First of all, you have to declare them first before assigning. Also, this uses the `,` operator which has a lower precedence than `=`, so the line is equivalent to `a; b; c = 10;`. As you can see, nothing really happens to `a` or `b` and only `c` is set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

### The comma used as an operator is called the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

For details, read a C standard, like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (§6.5.17) or later. The [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) is defined as:

> The  left  operand  of  a  comma  operator  is  evaluated  as  a  void  expression;  there  is  a [sequence  point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)  between  its  evaluation  and  that  of  the  right  operand.   Then  the  right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value

Of course, inside function calls like `printf("x=%d y=%d\n", x, y)` the comma is separating arguments. Inside macro invocations and definitions also. In that case, it is the **comma punctuator** (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.5.2, 6.7, 6.7.2.1, 6.7.2.2,6.7.2.3, 6.7.9)

If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), invoke it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You could get useful warnings.

Consider, if so allowed, to use the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (or other tools like [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/); you may contact me in 2021 by email to `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr`)

**Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) programs** like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). They rarely use the comma operator.

Answer (score -2):

In c language you can define the variable using one line

```
    int a,b,c;
```

This is same as

```
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
```

You can define and initialize this one like this

```
    int a,b,c;
    a=b=c=10;
```

if you write

```
    int a,b,c;
    a,b,c=10;
```

it will initialize c as 10 but others will not inilizes as 10;
a and b will be defined but not initialized it will return garbage value.

Comment: `int a=b=c=0;` - this won't work unless `b` and `c` are already defined. `int a,b,c=0;` - OP's code is slightly different, they don't have `int`.